# how to push tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Im pretty new to ios development and am starting with a viewcontroller that displays a table of data.  When I click on one of the cells, I try to push a tabbarcontroller into view.  It works, but I can't see the tabs and the view area is black instead of displaying either of the two default views associated with the tabbarcontroller.

If I set the tabbarcontroller as the intialviewcontroller, it works fine, but this breaks my design.

Any help appreciated.

UDPATE: this is how I'm pusing the tabbarcontroller into view

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let vc = TrialSiteViewController()

    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: post the code you are using to push tabbar

Comment: no worries, ive posted the code im using to push it into view, pretty straight forward.  the tab bar controller code has nothing additional added yet, just trying to get it to display correctly.  as i said before, i know it works because i can set it as the initial view controller and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried about four different ways to transition from my tableviewcontroller to my tabbarcontroller and the only way I could get this to work was to use a segue setup in my storyboard with an identifier, then call this when I click the cell.

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("trialSitesSegue", sender: self)
```

Probably obvious to a lot of IOS developers, but I am new to all this, so still thought I would share.